# In jqgrid the total is not showing for more than two columns

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

In jqgrid the total is showing only for two columns.I have 5 columns and want to get the separate total for each column to be shown in jqgrid on client side.I am using java Platform for creating JqGrid.

I am using 
jsonmap: function(obj) {
   return somevalue;} in all the column like amountSpent,unitOfMeasure,quantity,food and tea separately in colModel.

and

```
    var sum1 = jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('getCol', 'amountSpent', false, 'sum');
    var sum2 = jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('getCol', 'unitOfMeasure', false, 'sum');
    var sum3 = jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('getCol', 'quantity', false, 'sum');
    var sum4 = jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('getCol', 'food', false, 'sum');
    var sum5 = jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('getCol', 'tea', false, 'sum');

    jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('footerData', 'set', {transactionDate: 'Total:', 
        amountSpent: sum1, unitOfMeasure: sum2, quantity:sum3, food:sum4, tea:sum5});
```

Also i want to calculate the sum row wise...Is there any method to do that....

Please Reply...

Thanks in advance

Comment: why java and mysql tags? this is totally a jquery queston

Comment: i am using java as a platform and the data are entering into the grid through mysql via controller and dao layer.